# Proving that $R$ is Noetherian if and only if $X$ is finite.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, noetherian

I want to prove that if $\mathbb{F}$ is a finite field and $X$ any set, then $R$ a ring defined as :
$$ R:= \{f : X \to \mathbb{F}\ \big| \ f \ \text{is a function}\} $$

is Noetherian if and only if $X$ is finite.

I know the condition for Noetherian ring, but how do I work with a set, $X$ has no algebraic structure. I tried to think $X$ as a module, but can't see a suitable ring. Any ideas on how to proceed on this? Am I missing something important, please help. Thanks.

Comment: Are you aware that this ring is isomorphic to the direct product of $|X|$ copies of $\mathbb{F}$? In fact, in some developtments, this *is* the definition of $\prod_{x\in X}\mathbb{F}$.

Comment: I may be but can't see immidiately. Gotta check.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin does $|X|$ mean the cardinality? I mean $X$ can be infinite right?

Comment: Yes, it’s the cardinality of $X$. The point is that perhaps viewing $R$ as a set of $X$-tuples will help you see how the Noetherian property depends on whether $X$ is finite or not.

Comment: So I need to check that $\varphi : R \to \prod_{x \in X} \mathbb{F}$ defined as $\varphi(f) = \prod_{x \in X} f(x)$ is an isomorphism of rings ? right?

Comment: Thanks for your help , I will try to get it.

Comment: Again, it depends on your precise definition of product (as I said, in some developments, the product $\prod_i X_i$ is **defined** as the set fo function $f\colon I\to \cup X_i$ with $f(i)\in X_i$), but yes. Before doing *that*, though, see if you can prove the statement for the ring $\prod_{x\in X}\mathbb{F}$; otherwise, thinking about proving the isomorphism isn’t going to get you anywhere.

Comment: Sure, thanks for the suggestion. I am doing that right now :)

Comment: The "if" direction is completely trivial.

Comment: @EricWofsey "The "if" direction is completely trivial."

:-) r u sure that the other direction is not? :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $x\in X$, then
$$
I_x=\{f\in R: f(x)=0\}
$$
is an ideal of $R$. If $S\subseteq X$, then $I(S)=\bigcap_{x\in S}I_x$ is an ideal as well.

Prove that if $S\subsetneq T$, then $I(S)\supsetneq I(T)$.

Can you find an infinite descending chain of subsets of $X$, when $X$ is infinite?

For the converse, prove that *every* ideal of $R$ is of the form $I(S)$ for some $S\subseteq X$.